# How to pass generic callback as a concrete argument?

Tags: javascript, typescript

[TS Playground of the problem](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.2#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-skgb8QA)

```
function callStringFunction(callback: (s: string) => void) {
  callback("unknown string inputted by user");
}

function callNumberFunction(callback: (n: number) => void) {
  callback(4); // unknown number inputted by user
}

function genericFunction<T extends string | number>(value: T, genericCallback: (newValue: T) => void) {
  if (typeof value === "string") {
    console.log(value); // T is known to be a string here
    callStringFunction(genericCallback); // But this throws an error: (newValue: T) => void not assignable to (s: string) => void
  }
  else {
    console.log(value); // T is known to be a number here
    callNumberFunction(genericCallback); // But this throws an error: (newValue: T) => void not assignable to (n: number) => void
  }
}
```

How can I do this without resorting to: `callNumberFunction(cb as (n: number) => void)`

Since the type for `value` has been checked, shouldn't TypeScript be aware of the callback type as well?

Comment: Please provide a plaintext self-contained [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing. Ideally I could paste such code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/w2aDjW) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it. So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: Ok, no problem. I'll do that now

Comment: The compiler can't narrow generic *type parameters* via control flow analysis; even though you have successfully narrowed `value` to either `string` or `number`, *`T`* stays stubbornly the same the whole time; it does not narrow to `T extends string` or `T extends number`. There are open feature requests that might enable such behavior, like [ms/TS#33014](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33014), but for now there's no support for this. You'd need to use type assertions or refactor to proceed. Does that fully answer your question and I can write up an answer, or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, you can write an answer for this

Comment: Note that I didn't ask for a playground link; the example code should be plaintext and self-contained, in the body of the question itself.  A playground link is a great supplement but doesn't take the place of having the example fully in the question.  We can't require people navigate to external sites to see the full question.

Comment: The example should be minimal; extra code shouldn't bring up unrelated issues (e.g., checking for string and number is as easy as `typeof x === "string"` or `typeof x === "number"`; checking for `NaN` or what gets printed out if you wrap the object is fragile and complex and has nothing to do with your question).

Comment: The example should be verifiable; typos shouldn't be present unless you're asking about these typos.   `if (isString(value) {` is a syntax error, as you could note by looking at the code in an IDE.

Comment: [Here](https://tsplay.dev/NBkonm) is my suggested example code for your question; I could [edit] that into your question if you don't want to do it and if you don't mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the TypeScript compiler is not able to understand what you are doing here.  When you check `typeof value === "string"`, the compiler treats this as a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#typeof-type-guards) that narrows `value` from `T` to either `string` or `number`.  But it does nothing to narrow the type parameter `T` itself.

You would like the compiler to see `typeof value === "string"` and `value: T` together and narrow `T` from `T extends string | number` to `T extends string` or `T extends number` or perhaps just specific `string` and `number` type.  This does not happen.  `T` stays `T` throughout the function, and so `callStringFunction(genericCallback)` cannot be accepted.  The compiler still thinks that `T` might be some arbitrary subtype of  `string | number`.

There are open feature requests in GitHub to improve this situation somehow; see [microsoft/TypeScript#33014](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33014) for example.  Nothing has been implemented yet, though, partly because some "obvious" implementations would lead quickly to unsoundness.

For example, if I had `function f<T extends string | number>(value1: T, value2: T): void;`, I couldn't say that `value1` being a `string` implies that `value2` is also a `string`.  After all, maybe `value1` and `value2` are both `string | number`, as in the call `f(Math.random()<0.99 ? "" : 123, 123);`. There'd be a 99% chance of `value1` being a `string` while `value2` is a `number`.  So any code to deal with this would need to be carefully considered.

---

Furthermore, I can't think of a good way to refactor your code so that the compiler can see what you're doing as safe.  The types `string` and `number` are not considered *discriminant property* types, so I can't rewrite the args list to `genericFunction()` as a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions).  That would only work if you passed in a literal parameter like `function genericFunction<K extends "str" | "num">(type: K, val: Val[K], cb: (x: Val[K])=>void): void;`.  In such a case you could check `type` and then the compiler would narrow `val` and `cb` together.  But this isn't what you have, so it's not a straight refactoring.

For now I'd say that the best way to proceed is to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to just *tell* the compiler that you know what you're doing.  It's reasonable to write `val as Type` in cases where you are positive that `val` really is of type `Type` but the compiler cannot:

```
function genericFunction<T extends string | number>(
  value: T, genericCallback: (newValue: T) => void
) {
  if (typeof value === "string") {
    console.log(value); // T is known to be a string here
    callStringFunction(genericCallback as (newValue: string) => void);
  }
  else {
    console.log(value); // T is known to be a number here
    callNumberFunction(genericCallback as (newValue: number) => void);
  }
}
```

This fixes the errors, but places the burden of ensuring type safety on you.  It's not great, but it's the best I can figure out how to do as of now, without refactoring to an observably different algorithm. Oh well!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.2#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)